# netsh interface ipv6 show prefixpolicies equivalent for Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6

I'm hoping to identify the IPv4/IPv6 preference order configured on a host. As per the title, is there an equivalent of the following Windows command on a Linux host?

`netsh interface ipv6 show prefixpolicies`

I realise this can be manipulated in `/etc/gai.conf`, but I'd like to see the current preference info output to screen if possible.